# Is it possible to have a Controller component in a Backbone.js application?

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to have a Controller component that monitors change and tells Views to render. Is something like this possible in Backbone.js?

Comment: In case of model (change on model) : Rerendering a view is not a good idea at all, you can listen to changes and call render on change, but I recommend individual method for each attribute on change of that attribute (`this.model.on('chagen:attr',function(){changeAttr();})`) or use one of those backbone bind extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take take a look at Marionette.js its a library on top of Backbone, Think about it as JqueryUI of Jquery, this library already has a controller that I think will suit your needs if you use it toghter with the event aggregator component.

you can raise events from the views and let the controller listen for this events and act accordingly.

the links for the controller and event agreggator in marionette
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr

the link for the Marionette documentation

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette

the advantage of Marionette.js is that you can just use the Controller and that's it, its not an all or nothing library, just like JqueryUI the fact that you use the calendar does not mean that you need to use the rest of it.